# Error DialogResult no es miembro de forms

Tags: vb.net

Hola quería saber si me pueden ayudar en este error que me mando y no se como resolverlo se estaré agradecido

el error es este linea

estoy trabajando en VB.NET 2015 Componente DevExpress y Sql 2012

```
If accion = "new" Then
  If MessageBox.Show("¿Seguro que desea Registrar?", "Aviso Importante", 
     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
ClassGeneral.IURegistros("new", "0", cmbAceite.EditValue, cmbfiltro.EditValue, cmbplaca.EditValue, txtActual.EditValue, txtcambio.EditValue, dtFecha.EditValue)
  End If
End If
```

se los agradesco de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Bajo ciertas circunstancias, el uso de `Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes` puede resultar en el error:

> 'Forms' is not a member of 'Windows'

... o en español:

> 'Forms' no es miembro de 'Windows'

Así que tengo ciertas dudas en cuanto a la exactitud del mensaje de error que nos distes.

De cualquier forma, te sugiero de intentar reemplazar la expresión `Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes` con una de las 2 opciones siguientes:

```
DialogResult.Yes
```

o...

```
System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
```

Comment: gracias la primera me sirvio

Answer (score 0):

Ya no pongas

```
System.Windows.Forms
```

Pon ya directo DialogResult.Yes y veras que funciona a la perfección,

Comment: alguna referencia de tu afirmación ayudaría